# OVERRIDE_BY_INLINE in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin, inline

When implementing an interface in Kotlin with an `inline` function:

```
interface Foo {
    fun qux(fn: () -> Unit)
}

open class Bar : Foo {
    final override inline fun qux(fn: () -> Unit){TODO()}
}
```

the IDE (and possibly the compiler) complains with this message:

```
Override by an inline function
```

To suppress this message, I have to use the `@Suppress("OVERRIDE_BY_INLINE")` annotation. What is wrong?

What I am already aware:

- For a normal inline function, kotlinc will inline all usages of the inline function, but it will still compile the non-inline version of the function so that it can be called from Java (and possibly for backward compatibility or whatever reason).
- It is impossible to inline a virtual method. Inline simply means "copy all the code into the caller", but for invoking an abstract/interface method, the implementation is determined at runtime based on the actual class of the object involved, so it is not possible to know which implementation to copy into the function.

However, this isn't the case when invoking a final function. In the example above, when I invoke `bar.qux()`, the compiler can ensure that only this particular implementation will be used, and can safely inlined. It is irrelevant with whether it overrides the `Foo.qux` method -- calling `foo.qux` will use the non-inline version mentioned in point 1, and calling `bar.qux` can inline safely.

Is this warning there only to make sure developers are aware of this? Or are there side effects?

Comment: do you not also get "redundant modality modifier" for `final`?

Comment: No. `override` is `open` by default, and you need `final` for `inline`.

Comment: One thing that you definitely won't be able to do in an inlined override is to call the super method.

Comment: Oh I forgot to put the `open` modifier on `Bar`. It was `open` in my own code.

Comment: You can do things in inline methods that are _impossible_ in non-inlined methods.  Not all implementations of `Bar.qux` can be made to work for `foo.qux`.

Comment: What exactly are these things?

Comment: @SOFe what did you do in the end?

Comment: Suppress the warning, since nobody told me anything wrong with it

Answer (score 12):

I know this is pretty late, but here's why. You got this right:

> It is impossible to inline a virtual method.

But you should consider that, while `Bar.foo` is not virtual in the sense that it could be overridden (it can't be), it is virtual in the sense that a decision can be made to run it at runtime. Consider the following example which builds on your own:

```
interface Foo {
    fun qux(fn: () -> Unit)
}

open class Bar : Foo {
    final override inline fun qux(fn: () -> Unit){TODO()}
}

class Baz : Foo {
    override fun qux(fn: () -> Unit) = TODO()
}

fun main() {
    var foo: Foo = Bar()
    foo.qux { }          // calls Bar.qux
    foo = Baz()
    foo.qux { }          // calls Foo.qux
}
```

Here, `Bar.qux` is invoked initially, but `Baz.qux` is invoked the second time. So, not *every* call can be inlined. So why is this a warning and not a compiler error, like when we declare an `open fun` with the `inline` modifier? Consider the following:

```
val bar: Bar = Bar()
bar.qux { }
```

In this case, the compiler can safely inline all calls to `qux` on the variable `bar` because it's declared as a `Bar`. Even if the class is open as in your example, since the method itself is `final`, any derived type will always use exactly that `qux`. So this statement,

> In the example above, when I invoke bar.qux(), the compiler can ensure that only this particular implementation will be used, and can safely inlined.

is true only when the compiler statically knows the type of `bar` to be an actual `Bar`. It's an error when it's `open` because *none* of them can be inlined which definitely isn't the desired behavior, it's a warning when it's an override because only *some* of them can be inlined, which might not be the desired behavior.

[This example is available at play.kotlinlang.org](https://pl.kotl.in/lXc54U41W)