# Java/Kotlin callback syntax - do I really need 2 callback definitions after conversion to Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, callback

I have a problem that has been challenging me for a few days with no resolution (more directly, no resolution I feel is correct). The issue is around callbacks, Java implementation vs Kotlin implementation

I have this Java method:

```
public void setOnSelectionChange(MapControlUpdate mapMenuControl) {
    this.mapControlUpdate = mapMenuControl;
}

private MapControlUpdate mapControlUpdate;

public interface MapControlUpdate {
    void onSelectionChange(MAP_TYPE mapType);
}
```

Using the above implementation I have what I want (below) in both Java and Kotlin.

Java (before):

```
widgetMapType.setOnSelectionChange(mapType -> {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked: " + mapType, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```

Kotlin (before):

```
widgetMapType.setOnSelectionChange {
    Toast.makeText(context, "clicked: $it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

The new Kotlin code, after conversion is:

```
fun setOnSelectionChange(mapMenuControl: MapControlUpdate?) {
    mapControlUpdate = mapMenuControl
}

private var mapControlUpdate: MapControlUpdate? = null
```

After the conversion to Kotlin the Java usage remains unchanged but I need to change the Kotlin code as follows or I get a syntax error:

Kotlin (after):

```
widgetMapType.setMapMenuControl(object: WidgetMapType.MapControlUpdate {
    override fun onSelectionChange(mapType: WidgetMapType.MAP_TYPE?) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked: $mapType", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
})
```

In order to get back to where I'd like to be I found that the only solution appear to be to implement 2 callbacks; 1 to allow Java to work with the original syntax and another to allow Kotlin syntax to remain the same.

This is the code I'm using (it works):

```
var onSelectionChange: MapControlUpdate? = null

private var onSelectionChangeListener: ((MapDisplayTypes?) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnSelectionChange(listener: (MapDisplayTypes?) -> Unit){
    onSelectionChangeListener = listener
}
```

and I fire both callbacks as appropriate

```
onSelectionChange?.onSelectionChange(it)    // Java
onSelectionChangeListener?.invoke(it)   // Kotlin
```

I really cannot believe that there isn't a more correct method but my searches (here and on the web) have returns tons of examples for Kotlin and Java but they all align with my above examples based on the code (also shown above).  I suspect there maybe an annotation or something that I'm missing so finding no other solution I'm turning to the community here.

Thank you ahead of time!!

Comment: When you did the conversion to Kotlin, did you keep the exact same definition for the `MapControlUpdate` in Java? Part of what you want is using the Single Abstract Method (SAM) enhancement working with interfaces consisting of one method.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you will need to keep just your `interface MapControlUpdate` definition in Java.

Comment: This is probably the main reason they are adding SAM conversion for Kotlin interfaces in Kotlin 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two callbacks you would keep just one callback and convert as appropriate:

```
var onSelectionChange: MapControlUpdate? = null

fun setOnSelectionChange(listener: (WidgetMapType.MAP_TYPE?) -> Unit){
    onSelectionChangeListener = object : MapControlUpdate {
        override fun onSelectionChange(mapType: WidgetMapType.MAP_TYPE?) {
            listener(mapType)
        }
    }
}
```

Or write a helper function if `MapControlUpdate` is used more than once.

But the real solution is, as karmakaze says: keep the interface in Java until Kotlin 1.4 and then declare it as [`fun interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442419/function-interface-in-kotlin-1-4).