# Cannot pass lambda for interface in a method call with Kotlin (like how setOnClickListener does it)

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I created the class:

```
class SomeClass {
    var listener: SomeListener? = null

    interface SomeListener {
        fun onClick(v: View?)
    }

    fun addSomeListener(l: SomeListener){
        listener = l
    }

}
```

And I am calling it as follows, which works fine:

```
SomeClass().addSomeListener(object : SomeClass.SomeListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                // Do something
            }
        })
```

However, **the following syntax fails in Android Studio:**:

```
  SomeClass().addSomeListener{ view ->
                // Do something
        }
```

> Type mismatch. Required: SomeClass.SomeListener Found:
> () → Unit

---

I don't understand this, because Android's `setOnClickListener` method is implemented the same way:

```
/**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not
     * clickable, it becomes clickable.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will run
     *
     * @see #setClickable(boolean)
     */
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
        if (!isClickable()) {
            setClickable(true);
        }
        getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
    }
```

and...

```
/**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
     */
    public interface OnClickListener {
        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        void onClick(View v);
    }
```

that can obviously be called as:

```
someView.setOnClickListener { view ->
// Do something
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that Java interfaces are treated differently than Kotlin interfaces here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's calling `SAM Conversions`. If you want to make it work you need to add keyword `fun` for your interface so it will look like this :

```
fun interface SomeListener {
        fun onClick(v: View?)
    }
```

You can learn more about this by reading this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442419/function-interface-in-kotlin-1-4).

Comment: Functional (SAM) interfaces : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html