# How do I specify an ActionListener in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to add an ActionListener to a JButton in Kotlin. In Java, I would just write this:

```
JPanel makeButtonPanel() {
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  JButton dirButton = new JButton("Change directory");
  dirButton.addActionListener(e -> chooseDirectory());
  panel.add(dirButton)
  return panel;
}
```

But it's not so simple in Kotlin. I first tried this:

```
private fun makeButtonPanel() : JPanel {
  val panel = JPanel(FlowLayout())
  val dirButton = JButton("Choose")
  dirButton.addActionListener(e -> chooseDirectory()) // error message here
  // ...
}

private fun chooseDirectory() { ... }
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Type Mismatch
Required: ((ActionEvent!) -> Unit)!
Found: KFunction1<ActionEvent, Unit>
```

I understand that the ! means that this is a java method with uncertain nullability, but that doesn't help me understand how to write it. All I want it to do is call the chooseDirectory() method. There must be a clean, simple way to do this, but I don't see it.

Comment: Use curly braces (`{}` ) instead of normal brackets(`()`) for lambda expression in kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, you need to use braces (`{` `}`).

This is because **braces are a necessary part of defining a lambda** in Kotlin.  (That differs from languages like Java and Scala, where the necessary part is the `->` or `=>` arrow.  That's because in Kotlin the arrow is optional if there are one or no parameters; if one, the [`it`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) keyword is used.)

Without the braces, the code would call your `chooseDirectory()` function, and try to pass its *result* to `addActionListener()` — which obviously wouldn't work.

**Braces are also sufficient**: they're taken as defining a lambda unless you're giving the body of a function or method or an `if`/`when` branch.  (Again, this differs from most C/Java-like languages.  In Kotlin, if you just want a block scope, you have to use a construct such as [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html).)

As for the parentheses, they're optional here.  You could include them if you wanted:

```
dirButton.addActionListener({ chooseDirectory() })
```

But Kotlin has [a convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas) that **if a function's last parameter is a function, you can pass it *after* the parens**:

```
dirButton.addActionListener(){ chooseDirectory() }
```

And **if that would make the parens empty, then you can omit them** entirely:

```
dirButton.addActionListener{ chooseDirectory() }
```

That's to allow functions that look like new language syntax.  For example, you may have met the [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) function:

```
with(someObject) {
    itsProperty = someValue
}
```

That's just a perfectly ordinary function, defined in the standard library, and taking a function as its last parameter.  Similarly, [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html):

```
repeat(10) {
    // Some code to be run 10 times…
}
```

---

There's one further thing worth mentioning here.  In Kotlin, lambdas are one way to define [functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types), which are first-class types and can be defined, passed around, and used just like other types.  This differs from Java, which has traditionally used interfaces for those purposes — often interfaces with a Single Abstract Method (‘SAM interfaces’) — and in which lambdas are little more than syntactic sugar for defining an anonymous implementation of such an interface.

As a special case, for interoperability, Kotlin [allows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) a lambda to define an implementation of a Java SAM interface (or, since Kotlin 1.4, of a Kotlin [`fun interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59446061/10134209)), instead of a function.

**`ActionListener` is a Java SAM interface, which is why you can use a lambda here.**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out, and it was pretty simple. I just have to dispense with the parentheses and say

```
dirButton.addActionListener { chooseDirectory() }
```

I'm still not clear on when I should use braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: I'll try to explain those in an answer.  (There's too much for a comment!)

Comment: Braces are for defining it using lambda syntax. You could alternatively do `dirButton.addActionListener(::chooseDirectory)` to use functional reference syntax. And there are other ways you can specify it, like using anonymous object syntax or named function syntax. If you are doing nothing more than calling one other function, the functional reference syntax is typically preferable. Otherwise, lambdas usually result in the cleanest code.